Is it possible for an individual to update his/her android v10 to 11 or above
My current Android version 10 has no wireless debugging option and I want to modify my gaming performance through lowering or disabling battery usage. Also my phone its an Infinix smart HD brand.

Android Updates have to be distributed by the phone manufacturer, because they have to integrate it with thier custom software.
If you are willing to root it, then you may be able to find a solution.
